# Maven findbugs-maven-plugin Failing Due to Timeout

Tags: java, apache, maven, plugins, findbugs

I'm deploying a Java project using Electric Commander, and while running the site-deploy goal, the project fails during the integration tests while generating a report for the findbugs-maven-plugin.

The output below shows the Findbugs Report getting stuck after displaying "Fork Value is true" and after failing, it shows that "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project integration-module: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: Timeout: killed the sub-process -> [Help 1]"

```
[INFO] Generating "FindBugs Report" report    --- findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2
[INFO] Locale is en
[INFO] Fork Value is true

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Parent Module ......................... SUCCESS [2:27.472s]
[INFO] Module 1 .............................. SUCCESS [6:13.576s]
[INFO] Module 2 .............................. SUCCESS [7:12.407s]
[INFO] Module 3 .............................. SUCCESS [3:10.419s]
[INFO] Integration Tests Module .............. FAILURE [21:18.987s]
[INFO] Module 4 .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 40:30.544s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 24 18:00:08 CST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 238M/692M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project integration-module: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: Timeout: killed the sub-process -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :integration-module
```

I've also attempted this on my local machine with the debug option: `mvn site -X`, and I run into the same timeout issue. Here is the (shortened) debug output:

```
[INFO] Generating "FindBugs Report" report    --- findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2
[DEBUG] Inside canGenerateReport..... false
[DEBUG] canGenerate Src is true
[DEBUG] canGenerate is true
[DEBUG] Inside canGenerateReport..... false
[DEBUG] canGenerate Src is true
[DEBUG] canGenerate is true
[INFO] Locale is en
[DEBUG] ****** FindBugsMojo executeReport *******
[DEBUG] report Output Directory is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target/site
[DEBUG] Output Directory is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target/site
[DEBUG] Classes Directory is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target/classes
[DEBUG] resourceManager outputDirectory is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target
[DEBUG]   Plugin Artifacts to be added ->[org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.5.2:, org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-mojo:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-api:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.feature:gmaven-feature-api:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-1.5:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.feature:gmaven-feature-support:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all-minimal:jar:1.5.8:compile, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.2:compile, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.2:compile, jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.1:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-loader:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-support:jar:1.4:compile, org.sonatype.gshell:gshell-io:jar:2.4:compile, com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.12:compile, org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:jar:1.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-io:jar:1.1:compile, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10:compile, org.sonatype.gossip:gossip:jar:1.2:compile, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.1:compile, commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile, commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile, commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile, oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile, xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile, org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.7.4:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.1.3:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1.3:compile, xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.1.3:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.1.3:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.1.3:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7:compile, org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile, commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-doxia-tools:jar:1.2.1:compile, commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs-ant:jar:2.0.1:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs:jar:2.0.1:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:bcel:jar:2.0.1:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:jFormatString:jar:2.0.1:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile, dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile, jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile, jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile, xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile, xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile, xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile, com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile, asm:asm:jar:3.3:compile, asm:asm-tree:jar:3.3:compile, asm:asm-commons:jar:3.3:compile, jgoodies:plastic:jar:1.2.0:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-resources:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile]
[DEBUG] XML outputFile is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target/findbugsXml.xml
[DEBUG] XML output Directory is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target
[DEBUG] ****** FindBugsMojo executeFindbugs *******
[DEBUG] ****** Executing FindBugsMojo *******
[DEBUG] resourceManager outputDirectory is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target
[DEBUG]   Plugin Artifacts to be added -> [org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.5.2:, org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-mojo:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-api:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.feature:gmaven-feature-api:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-1.5:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.feature:gmaven-feature-support:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all-minimal:jar:1.5.8:compile, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.2:compile, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.2:compile, jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.1:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-loader:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-support:jar:1.4:compile, org.sonatype.gshell:gshell-io:jar:2.4:compile, com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.12:compile, org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:jar:1.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-io:jar:1.1:compile, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10:compile, org.sonatype.gossip:gossip:jar:1.2:compile, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.1:compile, commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile, commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile, commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile, oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile, xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile, org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.7.4:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.1.3:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1.3:compile, xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.1.3:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.1.3:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.1.3:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7:compile, org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile, commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-doxia-tools:jar:1.2.1:compile, commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs-ant:jar:2.0.1:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs:jar:2.0.1:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:bcel:jar:2.0.1:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:jFormatString:jar:2.0.1:compile, com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile, dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile, jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile, jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile, xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile, xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile, xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile, com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile, asm:asm:jar:3.3:compile, asm:asm-tree:jar:3.3:compile, asm:asm-commons:jar:3.3:compile, jgoodies:plastic:jar:1.2.0:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-resources:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile]
[DEBUG] outputFile is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target/findbugsXml.xml
[DEBUG] output Directory is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target
[DEBUG] Temp File is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target/findbugsTemp.xml
[INFO] Fork Value is true
[DEBUG] effort is Default
[DEBUG] effortParameter is default
[DEBUG] threshold is Default
[DEBUG] thresholdParameter is -medium
...
...
...
[DEBUG] Findbugs arg is -xml:withMessages
[DEBUG] Findbugs arg is -auxclasspathFromInput
[DEBUG] Findbugs arg is -projectName
[DEBUG] Findbugs arg is Integration Tests Module
[DEBUG] Findbugs arg is -effort:default
[DEBUG] Findbugs arg is -medium
[DEBUG] Findbugs arg is -nested:false
[DEBUG] Findbugs arg is -output
[DEBUG] Findbugs arg is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target/findbugsTemp.xml
[DEBUG] Findbugs arg is /Users/my_username/workspace/project/integration-module/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21:55 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-24T17:36:03-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 104M/252M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project integration-module: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: Timeout: killed the sub-process -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project integration-module: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: Timeout: killed the sub-process
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: Timeout: killed the sub-process
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: : Timeout: killed the sub-process
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.fork(Java.java:794)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:214)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:199)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:147)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:149)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:756)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:730)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindBugsMojo.executeFindbugs(FindBugsMojo.groovy:1004)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnCurrentN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindBugsMojo.executeReport(FindBugsMojo.groovy:640)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

In addition to the above attempts, I've also tried setting MAVEN_OPTS to include `-Dtimeout=25200000` (time in milliseconds equivalent to 7 hours) and some other ridiculous times, but the timeout is always approximately 600000, or 10 minutes (the default for findbugs-maven-plugin according to this: http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/findbugs-mojo.html#timeout).

The issue here is that we've already cut our release, so we can't change the code, which means I can't modify the plugin in the pom.

I have several report plugins that need to run for the integration tests module, but the Findbugs Report is the least important and can be taken out entirely, but it just so happens to be causing the issue.

Is there a way to override the default settings of findbugs-maven-plugin for the timeout option via the command line or using MAVEN_OPTS? If not, is there there a way to skip the Findbugs Report for a single module via the command line? Another possibility might be the option to finish running the site-deploy even if Findbugs times out; is there a Maven option to prevent site-deploy from failing? Any help with this problem would be great!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: @VenkateshManohar I resolved this issue a few months after this initial post, but I never got around to posting the resolution here. If I recall correctly, this ended up being a memory issue. I increased the default JVM memory setting for the scala-maven-plugin. The plugin documentation shows you how to configure the plugin settings: http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_compile.html. Hopefully this helps!